# How to highlight/change background of few lines only in sublime text 2?

Tags: colors, background, comments, sublimetext2

What am I trying to ask is not highlighting the whole background when I am currently on that line.

What I want to ask is if I am making comments and so I have seen a file few weeks back that only a few lines' background is totally different let's say red so when we are scrolling up and down it'll be lots easier to see OH! This is one of the sections.
I have been making huge comments like `/****/` with lots of `*` in order to separate each sections.

The picture below where the red part is something I am looking for.
A huge highlight for few rows which makes it easier to divide sections if needed to.

[image]

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Please [edit] it to describe in clear language exactly what you want. A screenshot would also be very helpful.

Comment: Sorry about that, just edited and added. Hopefully this will clear things up.  Was hard for myself trying to explain what I needed too ><"

Comment: you can use bookmarks. If you want sublime to save your bookmarks on close, their is a package for that (Sublime Bookmarks)